# Appcelerator jsPDF Show Image

Tags: appcelerator, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPDF to create pdf file using Appcelerator. I have been able to create texts, draw lines and put in colors, but when I am trying to insert images, it is not working.

Has anyone been able to insert images, both from the assets folder or using Base64. The code is being targeted for both Android and iOS as well. One of the project which I found in GitHub uses the classic approach and not the Alloy approach.

Comment: Bumping the topic in-case someone finds this and has any idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't personally use jsPDF, however https://github.com/Core-13/jsPDF-image-support this github project reports to support Titanium and Images.  Sorry I don't have the reputation to leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. No issues. I will check the link and if this works, then I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: I validated the project. It works smoothly for the classic projects, but when we try the same in Alloy, the images are not getting displayed. This is mainly due to the fact, there might be issues with the resource path. But this is a good direction to start. Will mark it as an answer.